# itertools: Python Module help creating combinations/permutations

Tags: python

I'm looking to create different word permutations without changing the order of the the string's invidual characters, rather just change the order.

For example, I'd like the string "**python generate combinations**" to print the following permutations:

python generate combinations

```
python combinations generate
generate python combinations
generate combinations python
combinations python generate
combinations generate python
```

I've looked at the itertools module, but couldn't find a proper iterator that would print the correct combinations

Comment: `itertools.combinations` will work, you just need to split the single string into words first (and then recombine the combination tuples, maybe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: from itertools import permutations

In [2]: map(' '.join, permutations("python generate combinations".split()))
Out[2]:
['python generate combinations',
 'python combinations generate',
 'generate python combinations',
 'generate combinations python',
 'combinations python generate',
 'combinations generate python']
```